# Do I need window trim for a chair rail

Tags: windows, trim

I have three close windows here. We are putting in a chair rail 6 inches above the sill and I was thinking of just putting a 30 degree miter cut on all the pieces across this bank of windows. I am wondering if it will look bad... or, would it look better to trim all the windows? They are just so close together I am not sure how to trim them out. Anyone have experience with close windows and a chair rail?
[image: three close windows]

Comment: Re-trimming the entire window package would solve your [other](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58898/how-to-fix-sagging-plaster-under-window) problem, too.

Comment: There were some good answers on this [similar question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/how-do-i-finish-the-open-end-of-a-chair-rail). One good suggestion was ending the window trim with a mitered return.

Answer (score 1):

Can I answer your second question first? If other windows in the vicinity are trimmed, then you should probably trim these windows. If you do, you want to take styling cues from everything around, but without that information, I'd imagine that something like a simple fireplace surround with 2 extra pilasters would be nice. (Comment back if that description made no sense and I'll mock a picture.)

If you don't trim the windows, I'd put bits of chair rail up with tape and see what you think. If you like them, go for it.

Comment: Here is a guide on how to install window trim. http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,218130,00.html